# Cant inject angular $filter service inside a factory

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a factory using angularjs, but when i try to inject $filter service in my factory i got this strange error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: undefinedFilterProvider <- undefinedFilter <- myfact
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.17/$injector/unpr?p0=undefinedFilterProvider%20%3C-%20undefinedFilter%20%3C-%20myfact
>       at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:63)
>       at angular.js:4031
>       at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4178)
>       at angular.js:4036
>       at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4178)
>       at $get (angular.js:16724)
>       at Object.myfact (app.js:4)
>       at Object.invoke (angular.js:4219)
>       at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (angular.js:4072)
>       at Object.invoke (angular.js:4219)

In my application I have many controllers that use the $filter service and I've never seen this error before.

Can someone give me a little help about this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.17"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  </body>

</html>


var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
var myfact = function($filter){
    var factory = {},
        filter = $filter(filter);
    return factory;
}
myfact.$inject = ['$filter'];
app.factory('myfact',myfact);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, myfact) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

[Plunker snippet](http://plnkr.co/edit/A3ubylbYZsXaFqZdgZmx?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You've got an error in your code within your anonymous function that you assign to myfact. You write `filter = $filter(filter)` but the parameter `filter` that you pass into `$filter` is undefined.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
var myfact = function($filter){
    var factory = {},
        filter = $filter(filter);   // <<-------  your error is on this line
    return factory;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i was really blind not to see it.